# Configure SocketCluster with nginx and ssl

Tags: ssl, nginx, socketcluster

I'm trying to setup my SocketCluster app to use SSL. I'm able to get it working on nginx without ssl but not with it. When ever I visit the site in the browser I get the nginx welcome page. If i visit port 8000 in the browser I'm able to see socket cluster but not if using the https protocol.

#### nginx config

```
server {
    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;

    server_name 104.xxx.54.xxx;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass https://localhost:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

#### server.js

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
var SocketCluster = require('socketcluster').SocketCluster;
require('dotenv').config();

var socketCluster = new SocketCluster({
  workers: Number(argv.w) || 3,
  brokers: Number(argv.b) || 1,
  port: Number(argv.p) || 8000,
  path: '/socket',
  appName: '...',
  workerController: __dirname + '/worker.js',
  brokerController: __dirname + '/broker.js',
  socketChannelLimit: 1000,
  crashWorkerOnError: argv['auto-reboot'] != false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  secure: true
});
```

Comment: doesn't your ssl port have to be 8000 as well not just default 443 and proxy pass for 8000.

Comment: @Dave I'm don't have the best understanding of nginx. What I want it to do is to render port 8000 when you visit 433 externally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be terminating SSL in the reverse-proxy. Your service listening on port 8000 is non-SSL. So your `proxy-pass` should use HTTP for the upstream connection and not HTTPS. Try:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
```

You may want to add an `X-Forwarded-Proto` header:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```